# ASP.net core dev container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

**Background:**
When working with Python-based containers, I usually create employ `docker-compose` to create a `dev.yml` override that ensures auto-reloading of Python files and provides the Python source using a volume (instead of adding the files). This way I can get really quick turnaround times when developing (basically just saving the file). Now I need to create a few services in ASP.net core and I am looking to do the same.

**TL;DR**:

Here's the essentials of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet
ADD src /app
RUN cd /app/src ; \
    dotnet build
ADD env/appsettings.json /app/src/TestService
CMD cd /app/src/TestService ; \
    dotnet run
```

Now, the question is: How can I fit this into an efficient development workflow. Of course I know I can just run Kestrel from Visual Studio, this is *not* my question. I need to run the container itself (it requires its Compose context as it has other service dependencies).
I am not too bothered with stepping in Visual Studio etc (I know VS is supposed to have Docker support, but I haven't been too impressed so far), but I need something slightly more efficient than rebuilding the container every time I make a code change.

I *think* I want this:

- Source code as volume (I know how to do that)
- Auto detect source changes, rebuild source, restart server (I don't know how to do that)

But I am also open to suggestions, especially if there is a canonical way of working with ASP.net core in Docker that I have failed to find.

Comment: Maybe this tool (which is a part of official asp.net core tools) will help: https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools. Here is sample usage: https://blog.jayway.com/2016/04/22/search-effective-workflow-docker-net-core/

Comment: `DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER` sounds like what I need. I missed that. Thanks. I will try to integrate into the Dockerfile now

Comment: @Krumelur, did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @Toshkuuu Yes. Source code in a volume, polling file watcher as above.

Comment: @Krumelur Could you be so kind and share you code please? I've been struggling for weeks now and can't seem to find a solution...

Comment: Basically reloading is built into the dotnet executable. I was just missing that it relies on inotify which does not work in Docker. Adding ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1 to the Dockerfile solves the problem for me.